# How to fill entity by uploading json file in symfony easyadmin bundle

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

i have an entity called User, and instead of filling the entity manually in easyadmin, i want to upload json file to fill the form automatically with available data,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Serializer Component? This can serialize and deserialize entities to and from JSON amongst other formats.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: yes, but still dont have a clue how to upload a file and fill the form using the file json content

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a form to upload the file, attach the file and deserialize on form submission. 
 Try a combination of the Serializer guide I linked above, and the guide on file uploads here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: great, i will..  Thank you